# @Transactional has no effect

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I'm currently having the issue that the `@Transactional` annotation doesn't seem to start a transaction for Neo4j, yet (it doesn't work with any of my *@Transactional* annotated methods, not just with the following example).

**Example:**

I have this method (`UserService.createUser`), which creates a user node in the Neo4j graph first and then creates the user (with additional information) in a MongoDB. (MongoDB doesn't support transactions, thus create the user-node first, then insert the entity into MongoDB and commit the Neo4j-transaction afterwards).

The method is annotated with `@Transactional` yet a `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException` is thrown when it comes to creating the user in Neo4j.

**Here is about my configuration and coding, respectively:**

Code based SDN-Neo4j configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement                        // mode = proxy
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "graph.repository")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "path_to.db";
    private static final String CONFIG_PATH = "path_to.properties";

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH)
            .loadPropertiesFromFile(CONFIG_PATH).newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

Service for creating the user in Neo4j and the MongoDB:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Inject
    private UserMdbRepository mdbUserRepository;    // MongoRepository
    @Inject
    private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public User createUser(User user) {
        // Create the graph-node first, because if this fails the user
        // shall not be created in the MongoDB
        this.neo4jTemplate.save(user);              // NotInTransactionException is thrown here
        // Then create the MongoDB-user. This can't be rolled back, but
        // if this fails, the Neo4j-modification shall be rolled back too
        return this.mdbUserRepository.save(user);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Side-notes:**

- I'm using spring version `3.2.3.RELEASE` and spring-data-neo4j version `2.3.0.M1`
- *UserService* and *Neo4jConfig* are in separate Maven artifacts
- Starting the server and SDN reading operations work so far, I'm just having troubles with writing operations
- I'm currently migrating our project from the tinkerpop-framework to SDN-Neo4j. This user creation-process has worked before (with tinkerpop), I just have to make it work again with SDN-Neo4j.
- I'm running the application in Jetty

Does anyone have any clue why this is not working (yet)?

I hope, this information is sufficient. If anything is missing, please let me know and I'll add it.

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that manual transaction-handling works, but of course I'd like to implement it the way "as it's meant to be".

```
    public User createUser(User user) throws ServiceException {
        Transaction tx = this.graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
        try {
            this.neo4jTemplate.save(user);
            User persistantUser = this.mdbUserRepository.save(user);
            tx.success();
            return persistantUser;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.failure();
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `TransactionManager` bean?

Comment: In the superclass `org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTransactionManager()`

Comment: How do you create the instance of UserService? Can you upgrade to 2.3.RC1 ? Oh if you use SDN against the server you won't be that happy, probably best to use your SDN code mostly via Cypher or implement a server extension using SDN and the embedded API. Better performance for remote server and SDN is planned for the future.

Comment: *UserService* is `@Inject`ed into a `@Controller` (which is in the same artifact as *Neo4jConfig*). All our maven artifacts run on the same server yet and we access the graph in embedded mode. Separation of concerns is planned in the future, though. I'll upgrade to 2.3.RC1 as soon, as I'm in the office :)

Comment: I just upgraded SDN Neo4j to `2.3.0.RC1` in order to that, I had to lift SND MongoDB to `1.3.0.M1`, but unfornately the `NotInTransactionException` hasn't gone away

Comment: Where are you scanning for your @Service annotated beans? My guess is at the `DispatcherServlet` level whereas the transactions are enabled at the `ContextLoaderListener`. (Or maybe you are scanning for the components twice). Post your configuration/web.xml...

Comment: HA! Good hint! That was not exactly the issue, since on the `DispatcherServlet` level I only scan for `@Configuration` beans, but I scanned for those services in a different spring-configuration-file than where I configured Neo4j (the `Neo4jConfig` bean). I'll post a more detailed explanation in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to m-deinum I finally found the issue. The problem was that I scanned for those components / services in a different spring-configuration-file, than where I configured SDN-Neo4j. I moved the component-scan for those packages which might require transactions to my `Neo4jConfig` and now it works

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement                        // mode = proxy
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "graph.repository")
@ComponentScan({
    "graph.component",
    "graph.service",
    "core.service"
})
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "path_to.db";
    private static final String CONFIG_PATH = "path_to.properties";

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH)
            .loadPropertiesFromFile(CONFIG_PATH).newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

I still will have to separate those components / services which require transactions from those which don't, though. However, this works for now.

I assume that the issue was that the other spring-configuration-file (which included the component-scan) was loaded before `Neo4jConfig`, since `neo4j:repositories` has to be put before `context:component-scan`. (See *Note* in Example 20.26. Composing repositories http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2948)